# How do I recover my Kingdom Rush Vengeance game save?

Tags: kingdom-rush-vengeance

After resetting my phone I lost my game save for [kingdom-rush-vengeance](/questions/tagged/kingdom-rush-vengeance). The game is connected to my Google account.

Is there a way to get my game save back?

Answer (score 1):

Well sadly for you, there is 2 options here.

1- If the game has an online account feature, there might be a cloud save. It could save you.

2- If you made a backup before resetting your phone, you might be able to dig through android files to find the save file.

If you don't have any of those, well I'm gonna guess you are screwed. Usually, when resetting a phone, it wipes anything that is not the OS recovery file. And then, since its flash memory, there is, as far as I know, no way to recover a file that was deleted.

Comment: I wonder if kingdom rush vengeance store stuff online. I mean I got partial save games in kingdom rush